# Create Lines in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

In the following code, I am adding three lines on the top of each other with a small gap from each other. However, I would like to know there is another way to make the code more modular?

I mean, instead of copy and pasting the `legend.append("line")` for each of them, i guess there might be better way to make into one rather than three.

[image]

```
    var legendData = [{ color: "white", text: "MyData" }];
        var legends = svg.selectAll("g legends").data(legendData);
        var legendBox = legends.enter()
             .append("g")


       legendBox.append("line")
          .attr("x1", 200)
          .attr("x2", 215)
          .attr("y1", 24)
          .attr("y2", 24)
          .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
          .attr("stroke-width", "2")


        legendBox.append("line")
          .attr("x1", 200)
          .attr("x2", 215)
          .attr("y1", 12)
          .attr("y2", 12)
          .attr("stroke", "green")
          .attr("stroke-width", "2")


        legendBox.append("line")
          .attr("x1", 200)
          .attr("x2", 215)
          .attr("y1", 0)
          .attr("y2", 0)
          .attr("stroke", "red")
          .attr("stroke-width", "2")
```

Comment: You should define the coordinates as data and then use the usual D3 selection/data matching pattern to create them.

Comment: Could you please illustrate with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The D3 way to do this is to define the coordinates as data and then select and match accordingly:

```
var data = [{x1: 200, x2: 215, y1: 24, y2: 24, color: "steelblue"},
            {x1: 200, x2: 215, y1: 12, y2: 12, color: "green"},
            {x1: 200, x2: 215, y1: 0, y2: 0, color: "red"}];

legendBox.selectAll("line").data(data)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.x1; })
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.x2; })
  .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.y1; })
  .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.y2; })
  .attr("stroke", function(d) { return d.color; })
  .attr("stroke-width", "2");
```

Comment: Awesome approach. However how/where totake into account of three colors ["red", "green", "steelblue"]

Comment: @casillas, Lars's solution is much more appropriate than the one you marked as accepted — if you consider this to be a d3 question. In response to your question, you can put the colors inside the objects of the `data` array and use a `function(d) {}` just like "x1", etc.

Comment: Yess, I agree meetamit.The only thing is missing to incorporate all color information

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Updated.

Comment: Marked as answer! Thanks Lars. it is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

If these lines were connected, you could have used polyline or polygon instead. But for this case, there is no other way (at least no serious one), then to define each line separately. You can, however, generate them like this:

```
colors = ["steelblue", "green", "red"];
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
   legendBox.append("line")
      .attr("x1", 200)
      .attr("x2", 215)
      .attr("y1", i*12)
      .attr("y2", i*12)
      .attr("stroke", colors[i])
      .attr("stroke-width", "2")
}
```

Comment: your solution worked very well. Great to know. I will mark as an answer once SOF allows me.